# CORS Error while uploading file from external url in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, url, upload, cors

I am trying to upload file from the external url, but having CORS error while accessing external url.

```
await fetch(url).then(function (res) { 

  response = res;

}).catch(function () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.toaster.error('Invalid URL', 'File Upload', {
      positionClass: 'toast-top-right'
    });
  });
});
```

showing following error

*Access to fetch at 'https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

Answer (score -2):

You can use `mode: 'no-cors'`,
Read [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
await fetch('https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf', {
  mode: "no-cors"
}).then(function (res) { 
  response = res;
}).catch(function () {
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.toaster.error('Invalid URL', 'File Upload', {
   positionClass: 'toast-top-right'
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: Uploading a file requires a content-type that requires a CORS preflight request. no-cors mode won’t work for that.

Comment: Try code, it will worked

Comment: I have tried with no-cors too, but having same issue